# Windows logon name of the user on whose behalf the code is being run

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I've googled and checked 2 resources.

I have msbuild.exe calling a myproject.proj file.

Is there a way to report the IIDentity of the identity running the process?

I did not find anything under the "Common MSBuild Project Properties" or "Jenkins Environment Variables".

I know I could write a custom task to wrap this call ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.name%28v=vs.100%29.aspx ), but I'm hoping there is something simpler out there.

"Common MSBuild Project Properties" : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx

"Jenkins Environment Variables" :
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try running the whoami command inside an exec task
such as:

```
<Exec Command="whoami" ConsoleToMSBuild="true">
  <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="UserName" />
</Exec>

<Message Text="Hello $(UserName), this is your script"/>
```

More about the command can be found here

[whoami cmd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771299.aspx)